# How to include R dependency in a python package

Tags: python, r, pip, bioconductor, pyproject.toml

I have a python project, that has an R dependency. The R package is available through [Biocunductor](https://bioconductor.org). It can be installed with the following code

```py
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages


utils = rpackages.importr("utils")
if not rpackages.isinstalled("BiocManager"):
    utils.install_packages("BiocManager")
robjects.r('BiocManager::install(pkgs="IsoCorrectoR", ask=FALSE)')
```

My project is set up with a `pyproject.toml` file, and a `pip install` works fine, but the R dependency is not installed.

With the `pyproject.toml` I see no place to execute the above code snippet. Executing it on runtime would be a possibility, but feels inelegant.

Comment: what is the name of the r package

Comment: It is [IsoCorrectoR](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IsoCorrectoR.html).

Comment: `robjects.r('BiocManager::install(pkgs="IsoCorrectoR", ask=FALSE)')` , above the name of the R package is 'XXX' can you try to substitute that with `IsoCorrectoR`

Comment: I wanted to keep it generic, and do not see that the actual package makes any difference, but so be it.

Comment: It is pretty easy to do this when packaging with anaconda/conda.  I am not sure it is possible with PIP.

Comment: sorry I mis-interpreted I thought you ran the code with XXX in the `pkgs=` input instead of representing a generic package

Comment: Python build/packaging tools are for Python libraries/scripts/dependencies. No OS packages, no other languages. Conda is more universal. Or OS-specific packages.